# FontAwesome Kit icons not conditionally rendering

Tags: reactjs, font-awesome

I am using the FontAwesome kit on my website, and I'm not having any issues displaying any icons.

However, now I just tried to do the following:

```
const [sort, setSort] = useState(true)

<i class={sort ? "fa-regular fa-angle-down" : "fa-regular fa-angle-up"}></i>
```

or

```
{sort ? <i class="fa-regular fa-angle-down"></i> : <i class="fa-angle fa-angle-up"></i>}
```

I can see from `console.log` and if I even do `sort.toString()` right where the icons are, that the state is changing when I click my button. However, in this case there is no rendering of the `fa-angle fa-chevron-up` icon. It just keeps showing the `fa-angle fa-angle-down` icon all the time. If I change the icons to some text, e.g:

```
{sort ? "foo" : "bar"}
```

Then it changes between the two. But not FontAwesome icons.

Am I doing something wrong, or...?

Comment: Idk if this *is* the cause, but try `className` instead of `class`

Comment: Yeah, I have tried that. Unfortunately that was not the case...

Comment: So were you able to resolve it? If not can you provide a bit more context (as in code snippet) ?